# awk with AND condition on two patterns misses in between lines which don not match

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, awk

Input_File:

```
    2020-09-24 12:08:18,085.085 INFO     38210f97f184 lCpkydbL6wlNNi0 94rXXKaa3KLamiJ prep - Benchmarking Data function ENDED
    2020-09-24 12:08:18,085.085 INFO     38210f97f184 lCpkydbL6wlNNi0 94rXXKaa3KLamiJ prep -                                                      
    Average_Unit_Price_00         0.000000         Average_Unit_Price
    Competition_Media_00          0.000000          Competition_Media
    2020-09-24 12:08:18,229.229 INFO     38210f97f184 lCpkydbL6wlNNi0 94rXXKaa3KLamiJ prep - Configure JSON function ENDED
    2020-09-24 12:08:18,302.302 INFO     38210f97f184 lCpkydbL6wlNNi0 94rXXKaa3KLamiJ prep - Writing into CSV STARTED
    2020-09-24 11:44:03,070.070 ERROR    38210f97f184 lCpkydbL6wlNNi0 94rXXKaa3KLamiJ prep - Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2646, in get_loc
        return self._engine.get_loc(key)
      File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1626, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
    KeyError: None
    2020-09-24 12:08:18,503.503 INFO     38210f97f184 lCpkydbL6wlNNi0 94rXXKaa3KLamiJ prep - *************Data Prep Step ENDED*****************
    2020-09-25 07:39:09,008.008 INFO     8ccaf8d81212 LWpHmfMDcu03xp5 J0ps4NHADvsyIFt model2 - model2 Time: 0:00:03.281901 
    2020-09-25 07:39:09,008.008 INFO     8ccaf8d81212 LWpHmfMDcu03xp5 J0ps4NHADvsyIFt model2 -
    2020-09-25 07:39:09,010.010 INFO     8ccaf8d81212 LWpHmfMDcu03xp5 J0ps4NHADvsyIFt model2 - Generating CModel_Meas_Agg STARTED
    2020-09-25 07:39:09,019.019 INFO     8ccaf8d81212 LWpHmfMDcu03xp5 J0ps4NHADvsyIFt model2 - CModel_Meas_All file has 21 observations
```

Command:

```
awk '/38210f97f184/&&/94rXXKaa3KLamiJ/' Input_File
```

Expected_Result:

```
    2020-09-24 12:08:18,085.085 INFO     38210f97f184 lCpkydbL6wlNNi0 94rXXKaa3KLamiJ prep - Benchmarking Data function ENDED
    2020-09-24 12:08:18,085.085 INFO     38210f97f184 lCpkydbL6wlNNi0 94rXXKaa3KLamiJ prep -                                                      
    Average_Unit_Price_00         0.000000         Average_Unit_Price
    Competition_Media_00          0.000000          Competition_Media
    2020-09-24 12:08:18,229.229 INFO     38210f97f184 lCpkydbL6wlNNi0 94rXXKaa3KLamiJ prep - Configure JSON function ENDED
    2020-09-24 12:08:18,302.302 INFO     38210f97f184 lCpkydbL6wlNNi0 94rXXKaa3KLamiJ prep - Writing into CSV STARTED
    2020-09-24 11:44:03,070.070 ERROR    38210f97f184 lCpkydbL6wlNNi0 94rXXKaa3KLamiJ prep - Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2646, in get_loc
        return self._engine.get_loc(key)
      File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1626, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
    KeyError: None
2020-09-24 12:08:18,503.503 INFO     38210f97f184 lCpkydbL6wlNNi0 94rXXKaa3KLamiJ prep - *************Data Prep Step ENDED*****************
```

Comment: Add your expected output.

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for showing your efforts. Could you please be more clear which lines you want? Your `awk` command is checking lines which have `38210f97f184` and `94rXXKaa3KLamiJ` which should print lines which have both of them, then what is not working exactly kindly do let us know.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Yes, i do need lines which have 38210f97f184 and 94rXXKaa3KLamiJ and even in between lines too which are between the matching patterns

Comment: @90's_jaddu, ok but your samples of expected output is not clear, kindly do fix it and let us know then.

Comment: @anubhava The expected result is the same as Input_File.

Comment: so even if a patterns are found in one line you want to output complete input file?

Comment: Yes with the lines in between matching patterns.

Comment: @90's_jaddu, please do wrap your samples in CODE TAGS they are not clear as of now(looking wise).

Comment: Yes have edited my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Since OP's samples are changed so adding this solution now.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  if($0~/38210f97f184.*94rXXKaa3KLamiJ/ && ++count==1){
    start=FNR
  }
  if($0~/38210f97f184.*94rXXKaa3KLamiJ/ && count>1){
    end=FNR
  }
  next
}
FNR>=start && FNR<=end
'  Input_file  Input_file
```

---

---

***Initial solution:*** Where as per OP's samples it was looking if even a single instance of matched regex is found print whole line is assumed here, with `awk` could you please try following.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  if($0~/38210f97f184 .* 94rXXKaa3KLamiJ/ || $0~ /94rXXKaa3KLamiJ .* 38210f97f184/){
    found=1
  }
  next
}
!found{
  exit
}
1
' Input_file  Input_file
```

OR with GNU `awk`:

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  if($0~/38210f97f184 .* 94rXXKaa3KLamiJ/ || $0~ /94rXXKaa3KLamiJ .* 38210f97f184/){
    found=1
    nextfile
  }
}
!found{
  exit
}
1
' Input_file  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Reading Input_file 2 times. First time checking if either of the pattern is found then set variable to `1`. In 2nd time Input_file reading simply checking if found is NOT set then exiting else it will print whole Input_file.

Comment: Instead of `next` I suggest using `nextfile` to speedup

Comment: Hi, I tried the same it end's up giving whole file with other unmatched-patterns too.

Comment: @90's_jaddu, please edit your samples as per anubhava sir;s comment. anubhava sir thanks for suggestion edited the code now cheers.

Comment: @90's_jaddu, please check my EDIT solution now and let me know then?

Comment: Hi @RavinderSingh13 Thanks for your effort and time i am able to fetch the result as expected. Thanks again sir.

Comment: @90's_jaddu, your welcome. Also it's a kind request to always be clear in your Q & A in first time itself cheers and happy learning

Comment: May be I misunderstood but if you copy line #7 and #8 from input to end of file then try that command. IMO those last 2 files should be in output.

Comment: @anubhava, hello sir, what I thought is OP needs line from line which has `38210f97f184 .* 94rXXKaa3KLamiJ` to till last line which has `38210f97f184 .* 94rXXKaa3KLamiJ`, please do let me know if I understood it wrong here.

Comment: @90's_jaddu, could you please confirm if my above comment is correct(on my thinking of question)?

Comment: Fair point. It appeared to me that OP has a log file to parse where each log statement can be multiline (e.g. stack trace in Java logs) and OP wants to print complete log statement where first line matches `/38210f97f184/ && /94rXXKaa3KLamiJ/`

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, Yes you are right on the approach what you came up with, i wanted line from line which has 38210f97f184 .* 94rXXKaa3KLamiJ to till last line which has 38210f97f184 .* 94rXXKaa3KLamiJ and all the in between lines between these matching patterns.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Hi, hope you are doing well, can we include ignore the lines that come in between which do not match the given search patterns in the same command? awk '
FNR==NR{
  if($0~/38210f97f184.*94rXXKaa3KLamiJ/ && ++count==1){
    start=FNR
  }
  if($0~/38210f97f184.*94rXXKaa3KLamiJ/ && count>1){
    end=FNR
  }
  next
}
FNR>=start && FNR<=end
'  Input_file  Input_file

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 because it is fetching the lines which do not macth the search patterns given in between.

Comment: @90's_jaddu, Hi, could you please open a new question for same with complete details and your tried code, we could discuss it there as this is old thread, it will confuse users if I edit answer now, let me know once you open it, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68020080/with-the-below-awk-command-i-am-getting-the-lines-which-do-not-match-the-search (Link for new question opened), kindly look into, thank you.

Comment: @90's_jaddu, yes I replied it there, we could discuss it there, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `awk` solution:

```
awk '!/^[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){2} / && p;
/^[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){2} / && p = (/38210f97f184/ && /94rXXKaa3KLamiJ/)' file
```

```
2020-09-24 12:08:18,085.085 INFO     38210f97f184 lCpkydbL6wlNNi0 94rXXKaa3KLamiJ prep - Benchmarking Data function ENDED
2020-09-24 12:08:18,085.085 INFO     38210f97f184 lCpkydbL6wlNNi0 94rXXKaa3KLamiJ prep -
Average_Unit_Price_00         0.000000         Average_Unit_Price
Competition_Media_00          0.000000          Competition_Media
2020-09-24 12:08:18,229.229 INFO     38210f97f184 lCpkydbL6wlNNi0 94rXXKaa3KLamiJ prep - Configure JSON function ENDED
2020-09-24 12:08:18,302.302 INFO     38210f97f184 lCpkydbL6wlNNi0 94rXXKaa3KLamiJ prep - Writing into CSV STARTED
2020-09-24 11:44:03,070.070 ERROR    38210f97f184 lCpkydbL6wlNNi0 94rXXKaa3KLamiJ prep - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2646, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1626, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: None
2020-09-24 12:08:18,503.503 INFO     38210f97f184 lCpkydbL6wlNNi0 94rXXKaa3KLamiJ prep - *************Data Prep Step ENDED*****************
```

Comment: It returns me whole file with other un-matched patterns too.

Comment: I have other patterns like  {2020-09-24 12:08:18,066.066 INFO     213643876lOlowdnjgdihwi 875jerbkfkdlsdhfli prep - Benchmarking Data function STARTED}

Even these lines which wont match the pattern are coming as result

Comment: But instead i want only the data between these matched patterns. Till the end of line where the same matching patterns exists.

Comment: Edited the question hope so you can make out the difference in actual input file and expected result posted, thank you sir